# How to correctly use forkJoin and switchMap with Promise to call two apis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-material, fork-join

I am making an api call in `Angular 9` as follows:

```
import {SubSink} from 'subsink';
...
...
async clickButton() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.Id.length; i++) {
        const hostId = await this.serviceA.Status(this.hostName[i]);
        this.subs.sink = this.serviceB.createDbEntry(hostId))
            .subscribe(s => {
                if (i === this.Id.length - 1) {
                    this.dialog.close();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Here `this.Id` is of type `any`

Now I want to make another api call `this.serviceC.runRetry(hostId)` after the successful completion of `this.serviceB.createDbEntry(hostId))`
And, I am doing it by adding `forkJoin` as below:

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

forkJoin(this.hostName.slice(0, this.Id.length).map(hostName => {
  return this.serviceA.Status(hostName).pipe(
    switchMap(hostId => this.serviceB.createDbEntry(hostId).pipe(map((dbEntry) => ({dbEntry, hostId})))),
    switchMap(resp => this.serviceC.runEntry(resp.hostId))
  )
})).subscribe(() => this.dialog.close());
```

The `serviceA Status` has the implementation as below:

```
public status<T>(host: string) {
    const hostString = host.toString();
    const Url = `${this.api}/${hostString}`;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    return this.http.get<rData<T>>(Url).toPromise();
}
```

I am getting a warning as below:

```
forkJoin Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative deprecated export function forkJoin<any>( sources: any):Observable<unknown[]>
```

I am also getting an error:
`TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise  >'.`

Comment: Could you show the implementation of serviceA.Status? Looks like it does not return Observable. From where exactly do you import forkJoin? 'rxjs'?

Comment: You can return promises to switchMap but you can’t pipe off them without wrapping in from

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you provide a working answer? I don't need to use `forkJoin` and open for other approach

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
const hostId = await this.serviceA.Status(this.hostName[i]);
```

and

```
return this.serviceA.Status(hostName).pipe( //...
```

In the first line, you're treating `serviceA.Status()` as a promise. In the second one, you're treating it as an observable. I'm assuming that the first one is correct (from the error message). Quick fix: convert a promise to an observable with the `from` operator. *Good* fix: don't mix promise paradigm with RxJS paradigm, stick to one (and best stick to Rx), otherwise it has potential of becoming real messy.